# Can you use the name of a Check-box to access its value?

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex

I am currently working on a Word document with ActiveX check-boxes.

You can use the following line of code to access a check-box :

`ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(n).OLEFormat.Object`

where n is an integer representing the position of that check-box in the document. Unfortunately for me, if any check-box or option button is added before a check-box, the position of that check-box change, thus a given `n` can point to a different check-box.

My question : is there a way to replace the `n` with the name (or something else as long as it cannot be changed by adding a new check-box) of the check-box ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to check the name of an ActiveX control, but not as an index value of a collection when the control is on the document surface. If you want to work like that I recommend using either the legacy Forms controls (same place in the Ribbon as the activeX controls list) or a Checkbox type of content control.

ActiveX controls can be indexed by a name when the control is on a VBA UserForm, because that's the environment the controls were designed for. Word "wraps" them up in a field code and treats them as a graphic, so VBA code has to go through a couple layers of interface in order to access them on a document as an ActiveX control.

The following code demonstrates how to address an ActiveX control by its name.

- Loop through the `InlineShapes` collection
- Check whether the type is an ActiveX control
- Check whether it's a checkbox
- Check the name property

Code:

```
Sub ActiveXControlByName()
    Dim ils As Word.InlineShape
    Dim cb As MSForms.CheckBox

    For Each ils In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If ils.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
            If ils.OleFormat.ClassType = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then
                Set cb = ils.OleFormat.Object
                If cb.Name = "cb2" Then
                    cb.value = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, ActiveX controls don't take names. The most convenient alternative is to use the Caption (the label text appearing beside the checkbox). You have to take an approach like you do in PowerPoint, where you poll each shape to find the one that meets your criterion:

```
Sub GetCheckBoxValue()
    For x = 1 To ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
        If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(x).OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "ActiveX Label Text" Then
            CheckboxValue = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(x).OLEFormat.Object.value
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```